# Getting the name of a keypress

Tags: xorg

How could one write a script or programme that waits for a keypress
and outputs its X-name (<kbd>Return</kbd>, <kbd>BackSpace</kbd>, etc.) including modifiers, in a format accepted by `xdotool` (eg. <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>)?